# MAPIFolder deprecated so workaround for Outlook programming?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, office-2010, outlook-object-model

MSDN says [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.aspx) of the MAPIFolder interface (Outlook programming with WPF):

> This interface is deprecated; do not
>   use this interface. Instead use the
>   interface Folder to access all method,
>   property, and event members of the COM
>   object Folder.

I am trying to get the Drafts folder like so:

`Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);`

How do I do the above without using the MAPIFolder (which is deprecated)? 
I guess I don't understand what MSDN is saying (using the Folder interface to access all method etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply cast it to Outlook.Folder, i.e.

```
Outlook.Folder oFolder = (Outlook.Folder) olNS.GetDefaultFolder( Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFoderDrafts)
```

Admittedly, the MSDN is rather unclear there. You can think of the Folder interface as a wrapper around the MAPIFolder, with additional support for events.

As I sidenote, I would take the whole 'deprecated' thing with a grain of salt. I'd bet MAPIFolder is here to stay, at least for a couple more versions of Outlook.