# Difference between Outlook.Folder and Outlok.MAPIFolder

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm not clear on the difference between the classes `Folder` and `MAPIFolder` in the namespace `Outlook`. When I review the code in the net, some use the first, while others use the other syntax and I can't really determine if:

- it's just because of their ignorance (and even less I can tell which group is the right one)
- it's some kind of legacy (usage for different versions of Outlook)
- it's the very same thing (something I'm fairly sure isn't true but one never knows)
- it's an inheritance structure (and what to use when)
- it's simply a way to avoid type issues (casting and `as`-ing)
- it's other reason(s) entirely (and if so, which)

Here's the code I'm using for obtaining those two.

```
Outlook.Folder defaultContactsFolder_1 = 
  this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
    Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts) as Outlook.Folder;

Outlook.MAPIFolder defaultContactFolder_2 = 
  this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(
    Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`Folder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folder.aspx) has superseded [`MAPIFolder` which is now deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.aspx). See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6213749/175679). [`Folder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folder.aspx) has additional event hooks as compared to `MAPIFolder`

`Application.Session == Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")` - they are interchangeable. See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957861/175679).

`MAPIFolder` and [`GetNamespace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationclass.getnamespace)  are carry overs from Outlook 2003 and below - they've just been kept for backwards compatibility. There's no way to avoid type casting with VSTO - you will constantly be boxing and unboxing.